# Apply simple script to specific tabs in a Google Sheet (I know zero code)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to run the following script to all but the last tab in a Google Sheet:

```
function ClearAll() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = 'ScriptTest';
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,LR);
  range.uncheck();
}
```

As you can see it is only referencing a single tab "ScriptTest".

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested)

```
// uncheck every checkbox in Column A of every sheet except for the last sheet

function ClearAll() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets() 
    var sheetscount = sheets.length
    for (s=0;s<sheetscount-1;s++){
        var LR = sheets[s].getLastRow();
        var range = sheets[s].getRange(1,1,LR);
        range.uncheck();
    }
}
```

---

**LOGIC**

- `var sheets = ss.getSheets()`  - this returns ALL the sheets
- `var sheetscount = sheets.length` - counts how many sheets are in the spreadsheet
- `for (s=0;s<sheetscount-1;s++){`

  - create a loop that will has a length of the total number of sheets minus one (i.e. that last sheet doesn't get processed.)
  - `sheets[s]` - this is used instead of `getSheetByName(sheetname)`. Each time the loop restarts, the value of `s` increments by one, so the sheet ID starts off as `sheets[0]`, then `sheets[1]`and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. Have a wonderful day!!!

Comment: If this answer was helpful, then you might consider “[accepting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)” it.